# gSOAP DOM parser issue

Tags: c++, xml, dom, utf-8, gsoap

I try to use gSOAP 2.8.10 DOM parser to parse simple XML containing UTF8-encoded cyrillic text.
I created VC++ console application, added to project `soapC.cpp` and `soapns.cpp`.

soapns.cpp:

```
#include <soap.nsmap>
```

soap.nsmap:

```
#include "soapH.h"
SOAP_NMAC struct Namespace namespaces[] =
{
    {"SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "http://www.w3.org   /*/soap-envelope", NULL},
    {"SOAP-ENC", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "http://www.w3.org/*/soap-encoding", NULL},
    {"xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.w3.org/*/XMLSchema-instance", NULL},
    {"xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "http://www.w3.org/*/XMLSchema", NULL},
    {"ns2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/", NULL, NULL},
    {"ns1", "http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200", NULL, NULL},
    {"ns3", "http://tempuri.org/", NULL, NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

`soapC.cpp, soap.H, soap.nsmap` are generated using soapcpp2.exe utility.

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdsoap2.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

void print_in_hex(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string::const_iterator ch;
    for(ch = str.begin(); ch != str.end(); ++ch)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex <<
        std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase <<
            static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(*ch)) << " ";

    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// Sample XML content

const std::string Xml =
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
<entry>\
<properties>\
<Id>a8a4cf87-9497-4078-9166-0737a55ca7fc</Id>\
<Name>\xD0\x9D\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB0\xD1\x8F\x20\xD0\xBA\
\xD0\xBE\xD0\xBB\xD0\xBB\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBA\xD1\x86\xD0\xB8\xD1\x8F</Name>\
</properties>\
</entry>";

const std::string correctName = "\xD0\x9D\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB0\xD1\x8F\x20\xD0\xBA\
\xD0\xBE\xD0\xBB\xD0\xBB\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBA\xD1\x86\xD0\xB8\xD1\x8F";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream inputStream;
    inputStream.str(Xml);
    struct soap_dom_element entry(soap_new());
    soap_set_mode(entry.soap, SOAP_DOM_TREE | SOAP_C_UTFSTRING);
    inputStream >> entry;
    soap_dom_element_iterator it = entry.find( NULL, "Name");
    if( it != entry.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Original content:" << std::endl; 
        print_in_hex(correctName);
        std::string name = (*it).data;
        std::cout << "Parsed content:" << std::endl;
        print_in_hex(name);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Original content:
D0 9D D0 BE D0 B2 D0 B0 D1 8F 20 D0 BA D0 BE D0 BB D0 BB D0 B5 D0 BA D1 86 D0 B8 D1 8F
Parsed content:
C3 90 9D D0 BE D0 B2 D0 B0 D1 8F 20 D0 BA D0 BE D0 BB D0 BB D0 B5 D0 BA D1 86 D0 B8 D1 8F
```

When XML is being read from stream, gSOAP puts two bytes `0xC3 0x90` instead of first byte `0xD0` of the original content of `<Name>` tag. As a result I see `'??овая коллекция'` instead of `'Новая коллекция'` when the text is decoded from UTF8 to Windows-1251. Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in gSOAP 2.8.16